# how to remove back button on button click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I am trying to move one page to to another using **$state.go** function. I am able to do that, but when the user clicks on the button, it creates a **back button** on next page. I don't want  this when the user clicks on this main screen button.

I will explain again I have one button on main screen. On click I go to another screen, after I move it, it shows the back button on top header. I don't want this, but after that, if the user click moves to any page, it shows the back button. I don't want the navigation back button on the first screen. After that, I want here is my code
(http://plnkr.co/edit/J4XI8hjCgvIUeVV89kYG?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/css/ionic.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="ionic@1.0.0-beta.1" data-semver="1.0.0-beta.1" src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>

</html>
```

---

```
.controller('a', function($scope, $stateParams,$state) {

  $scope.moveto=function(){
    alert('--')
    $state.go('app.playlists')

  }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/)  before calling `$state.go('app.playlists')`

Try like this

```
.controller('a', function($scope, $stateParams,$state,$ionicHistory) {

  $scope.moveto=function(){
    alert('--')
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableBack: true
  });
    $state.go('app.playlists')

  }

})
```

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/77ThFDVryrvbblmToHgP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use the hide-back-button attribute

```
<ion-view title="Playlists" hide-back-button="{{hideBackButton}}">

.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.hideBackButton = true;
})
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/vIhljr0kdNB8u0rWWwCw?p=preview